# coping an array from one object to another object

Tags: c++

```
set &set::operator=(set const &s) {
elems = new int[s.num_elems];
num_elems = *(new size_t);
for (size_t i = 0; i < s.num_elems; i++) {//i am getting error in this line on "=" saying " a value type int* cannot be assigned tpo an entity of type int".
    elems[i] = &(s.elems[i]);
}
num_elems = s.num_elems;

return *this;
```

};

i am trying to copy an object to another object they each has two private size_t num_elems and int *elems.i have tried changing the pointer symbols and copying the array directly but it gives me error everytime

Comment: What do you expect "`*(new size_t);`" to accomplish? This part makes no sense to me.

Comment: He leaked and de-referenced the leak to capture the undefined value into his object.

Comment: Please never use new and delete in C++. If you need dynamic memory, use `std::vector` as container for allocated dynamic memory. This will help to avoid a lot of issues with pointers and focus on the problem you solve.

Comment: @TarekDakhran except that he's apparently trying to implement a set data structure. I wouldn't use an std container to implement my own container lol

Comment: and I would never go as far as say never to anything. I'm no justin beiber fan but never say never :D

Comment: @AdamZahran I would -- e.g. if you're implementing a priority queue stored in contiguous memory then why not use `vector` for the memory block?

Comment: Well yeah, you have a very good point :D I still wouldn't use the `std::vector` and would instead have my own simpler/faster implementation of a dynamic buffer. But you have a very valid point nonetheless

Answer (score 1):

This line is bad: `num_elems = *(new size_t);`
It just leaks a few bytes and does nothing useful. Delete it.

Then there is a problem where you are assigning the address of `s.elems[i]` into `elems[i]`. Which is not right because `elems[i]` is an integer, and the address of `s.elems[i]` is... well, an address.

So you need to change this line: `elems[i] = &(s.elems[i]);` to this: `elems[i] = s.elems[i];`

A few tips:

- `&` this is called the "address of" operator. It gets the address of where something is in memory.
- `*` this is called the "pointer dereference" operator. It helps you access what the pointer is pointing at.
- When you access an array with square brackets, like this: `elems[i]` you're de-referencing it. Which means you're using the value that the pointer is pointing at. It's the same as doing this: `*(elems + i)`
- Study your pointers :D They're a little tricky at first but they get easier with time and practice.